# Should EF6 DbContext be injected as Scoped or Transient if transactions need to be executed both in batches and asynchronously individually?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

About 2 years ago, we made the change from ADO.net over to Entity Framework 6. Initially, we simply instantiated our `DbContexts` where we needed them. However, at some point we started down the path of prepping for implementing Dependency Injection in the solution. As such, our `DbContexts` were injected into our MVC controller constructors, and then the necessary logic classes were instantiated directly using the `DbContexts`. For awhile, this worked great as we had certain `IRepository` implementations that allowed us to manipulate dozens of entities across multiple repositories, and save them all with a single `SaveChanges` call.

However, over time, we've started to adapt a more purist DI approach where all our new classes are being injected (rather than instantiated). As a side-effect, we've started moving away from repositories and towards using EF as just a core repository across our solution. This has lead to us building modules in our application that perform their unit of work and save their changes. So rather than having dozens of repositories being used and accessed to perform an operation, we simply use the `DbContext`.

Initially, this worked out alright as we were injecting our `DbContexts` as scoped, and the functionality was unchanged. However, with the move towards more self-contained, self-saving modules, we've encountered concurrency errors with our new functionality. We managed to solve the concurrency issues by switching the DI configuration for our `DbContexts` over to transient. This presented each self-contained module with a new `DbContext` and they were able to execute and save without caring what the other modules were doing.

However, switching the `DbContexts` over to transient had the unfortunate side-effect of making it impossible to switch our legacy modules over to our DI container as they relied on a singular shared `DbContext` across all of their injected dependencies.

So my main conundrum is whether we should make our `DbContexts` Scoped or Transient. And if we do settle on scoped, how do we write our new modules so that they can execute in a parallel way? And if we settle on transient, how can we preserve the functionality in our dozens of legacy classes that are still developed and used?

---

## Scoped

### Pros

- Single `DbContext` per request. No worries about entities being tracked in different contexts, and saves can be done wholesale.
- Legacy Code does not need any major changes to be switched to DI.

### Cons

- Unrelated tasks can't execute concurrently using the same context.
- Developers must constantly be aware of the state of the current context. They need to be wary of any side-effects from other classes utilizing the same context.
- `System.NotSupportedException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'` thrown during concurrent operations.

---

## Transient

### Pros

- New `DbContext` per class. No worries about locking context while performing most operations on the context.
- Modules become self-contained and you don't need to worry about side-effects from other classes.

### Cons

- Receiving an entity from one context and attempting to use it in a different context instance can cause errors.
- No ability to perform batch operations across multiple different classes sharing the same context.

---

Here is a demo algorithm to force a concurrency error for a scoped context. It presents a possible use-case for the transient injection.

```cs
// Logic Class
public class DemoEmrSaver
{
    private readonly DbContext_dbContext;

    public DemoEmrSaver(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task CreateEmrs(int number)
    {
        Contract.Assert(number > 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
            CreateEmr();

        return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void CreateEmr()
    {
        var emr = new EMR
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        _dbContext.EMRs.Add(emr);
    }
}

// In a controller
public async Task<IActionResult> TestAsync()
{
    // in reality, this would be two different services.
    var emrSaver1 = new DemoEmrSaver(_dbContext);
    var emrSaver2 = new DemoEmrSaver(_dbContext);

    await Task.WhenAll(emrSaver1.CreateEmrs(5), emrSaver2.CreateEmrs(5));

    return Json(true);
}
```

And here is a demo of how the older services often functioned

```cs
public class DemoEmrSaver
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public DemoEmrSaver(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void CreateEmrs(int number)
    {
        Contract.Assert(number > 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
            CreateEmr();
    }
    private void CreateEmr()
    {
        var emr = new EMR
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        _dbContext.EMRs.Add(emr);
    }
}

// controller action
public async Task<IActionResult> TestAsync()
{
    var emrSaver1 = new DemoEmrSaver(_dbContext);
    var emrSaver2 = new DemoEmrSaver(_dbContext);

    emrSaver1.CreateEmrs(5);
    emrSaver2.CreateEmrs(5);

    await _catcContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Json(true);
}
```

Is there some sort of middle ground that won't require massive overhauls to the old code, but that still enables my new modules to be defined and utilized in a simple way (e.g. avoiding having to pass a `Func` of some sort into each constructor to get a new instance, and avoid having to specifically a request a fresh `DbContext` everywhere I need one?

Also probably important, I'm using the .Net Core DI Container from the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace.

Comment: Which DI container do you work with? Does it support per-thread scope?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using the .Net Core Dependency injection from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: Per thread scope can be dangerous with await/async, since it could be other thread the one that takes the operation after an await

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use an artificial scopes were you have this difficulties?

For example, we have some background services in our codebase, when they are used inside a normal AspNet core web app, as you say, the context are bounded to the requests, but for our console apps, we do not have the concept of scoped, so we have to define it ourselves.

To create an artificial scope, simply inject an `IServiceScopeFactory`, then, everything inside will utilize the new, separated context.

```
public class SchedulerService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeService;

    public SchedulerService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeService)
    {
        _scopeService = scopeService;
    }

    public void EnqueueOrder(Guid? recurrentId)
    {
        // Everything you ask here will be created as if was a new scope,
        // like a request in aspnet core web apps
        using (var scope = _scopeService.CreateScope())
        {
            var recurrencyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRecurrencyService>();
            // This service, and their injected services (like the context)
            // will be created as if was the same scope
            recurrencyService.ProcessScheduledOrder(recurrentId);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can control the lifetime of the scoped services, helping you to share the same context inside that block.

I would recommend to create just one service this way, and then inside the service program everything as normal, this way your code will be keep clean and easier to read, so, do like the example:

```
using (var scope = _scopeService.CreateScope())
{
    var recurrencyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRecurrencyService>();
    // In this service you can do everything and is
    // contained in the same service
    recurrencyService.ProcessScheduledOrder(recurrentId);
}
```

Please do not add complex code inside the using, something like

```
using (var scope = _scopeService.CreateScope())
{
    var recurrencyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRecurrencyService>();
    var otherService= scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OtherService>();
    var moreServices = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MoreServices>();

    var something = recurrencyService.SomeCall();
    var pleaseDoNotMakeComplexLogicInsideTheUsing = otherService.OtherMethod(something);
    ...
}
```

### EDIT

> My fear with this approach is that it's applying a Service Locator
>   pattern, and I've often seen that dismissed as an anti-pattern where
>   DI is concerned

An anti-pattern would be to use this as normal work, but I am suggesting to introduce it in just one part, there are limits and constraints to what DI can do and can help you with your problems.

For example, property injection (no constructor injection) are also a code smell, but it is not banned or deleted of the framework, because in some cases is the only solution, or the most simple, and keeping things simple is more important than keep all the good practices (even best practices are not white or black, sometimes you will have to do trade-offs between follow one or other principle).

My solution should be in one part of your program, not for everything, that is why I recommend to create just one service, and from there make all the services, you can not use constructor injection to break the scoped life cycle, so `IServiceScopeFactory` exists just for that.

And sure, it is not for general use, but to help with lifecycle problems like you have.

If you are worried about `calling GetService<SomeClass>` you can create an abstraction to keep your code clean, for example, I created this general service:

```
public class ScopedExecutor
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedExecutor> _logger;

    public ScopedExecutor(
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
        ILogger<ScopedExecutor> logger)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<T> ScopedAction<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, Task<T>> action)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            return await action(scope.ServiceProvider);
        }
    }

    public async Task ScopedAction(Func<IServiceProvider, Task> action)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            await action(scope.ServiceProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have this extra layer (you could make this in the same class as the previous)

```
public class ScopedExecutorService<TService>
{
    private readonly ScopedExecutor _scopedExecutor;

    public ScopedExecutorService(
        ScopedExecutor scopedExecutor)
    {
        _scopedExecutor = scopedExecutor;
    }

    public Task<T> ScopedActionService<T>(Func<TService, Task<T>> action)
    {
        return _scopedExecutor.ScopedAction(serviceProvider =>
            action(
                serviceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<TService>()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Now, where you need your services as a separated context, you can use it something like this

```
public class IvrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingGrpcImpl : IvrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingService.IvrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingServiceBase
{
    private readonly GrpcExecutorService<IvrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingHttpClient> _grpcExecutorService;

    public IvrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingGrpcImpl(GrpcExecutorService<IvrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingHttpClient> grpcExecutorService)
    {
        _grpcExecutorService = grpcExecutorService;
    }

    public override async Task<RetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingResponse> RetrieveBillHistoryListFinancing(RetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingRequest retrieveBillHistoryListFinancingRequest, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return await _grpcExecutorService
            .ScopedLoggingExceptionHttpActionService(async ivrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingHttpClient =>
                await ivrRetrieveBillHistoryListFinancingHttpClient
                    .RetrieveBillHistoryListFinancing(retrieveBillHistoryListFinancingRequest)
            );
    }
}
```

As you see, no `service.GetService` is called in the business code, just in one place in our toolkit

Comment: My fear with this approach is that it's applying a Service Locator pattern, and I've often seen that dismissed as an anti-pattern where DI is concerned.

Comment: Edited to address your worries, I hope it helps!